# <Image> tags not rendering after AJAX call succeeds

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to finish [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial). It is running but when the search is ran, the results list does not render a picture like expected:

[image]

[image]

The code is at `mobile/react_native/ray_wenderlich_tutorial/PropertySearch` of [my repo](https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/tutorials), only the iOS version is working.

The default API call is http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api?country=uk&pretty=1&encoding=json&listing_type=buy&action=search_listings&page=1&place_name=london

Visiting an `img_url`, such as https://imgs.nestimg.com/flat_london_106825165453517629.jpg, does work.

I am not seeing errors in console, just that the `<Image>` seems to not render, silently.

Comment: I can't seems to find PropertySearch source file. Do you actually mean SearchResults instead?

Comment: Could you replace parts of this question with the actual fetching + rendering logic of the code since currently it's very hard to find correct pieces from your repo?